# Laravel 10 custom login/registration not going to dashboard page

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-10, laravel-controller

I am trying to make my own custom laravel 10 login/registration because i didn't want to use the breez package because i wanted to learn how do you make a login/registrasion by yourself.

But I cant seem to get past the authentication of the dashboard page.

I am using an if statment `if(Auth::check())` on my dashboard function to authenticate the user in the database.

but for me this isn't working because i keep getting the error message from the redirect back to the login page (**This only happens when I register a new user into the database**) but whenever I try loging in I get the success message from my login function (**See code futher down**) while still being in the login page.

**AuthController (Dashboard):**

```
public function dashboard(): View
    {
        if(Auth::check()) {
            return view('auth.dashboard');
        }

        return view('auth.login')->with('error', 'You are not allowed to access');
    }
```

**AuthController (Login):**

```
public function loginPost(Request $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        $request->validate([
           'email' => 'required',
           'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        if(Auth::attempt($credentials)) {

            $request->session()->regenerate();

            return redirect()->intended(route('dashboard'))->with('success', 'You have successfully logged in');
        }

        return redirect(route('login'))->with('error', 'Oppes! You have entered invalid credentials');
    }
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/register', [AuthController::class, 'register'])->name('register');
Route::post('/register', [AuthController::class, 'registerPost'])->name('register.post');
Route::get('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login'])->name('login');
Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'loginPost'])->name('login.post');
Route::get('/dashboard', [AuthController::class, 'dashboard'])->name('dashboard');
Route::post('/logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout'])->middleware('auth')->name('logout');
```

I havn't found any solution yet so if someone can help me it will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Routes

```
Route::get('login', [FrontendAuthController::class, 'loginGet'])->name('login');
Route::post('login', [FrontendAuthController::class, 'loginPost']);
Route::post('logout', [FrontendAuthController::class, 'logout'])->name('logout');
Route::get('register', [FrontendAuthController::class, 'registerGet'])->name('register');
Route::post('register', [FrontendAuthController::class, 'registerPost']);
```

Your controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Frontend;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class FrontendAuthController extends Controller
{
    public function loginGet(Request $request)
    {
        return view('front.auth.login');
    }

    public function loginPost(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
        ], [
            'email.required' => 'The email field is required.',
            'email.email' => 'Please enter a valid email address.',
            'password.required' => 'The password field is required.',
        ]);

        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return redirect()->intended('/');
        } else {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['email' => 'These credentials do not match our records.']);
        }
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        Auth::logout();
        Session::flush(); // Clear all session data
        Session::regenerate(); // Regenerate the session ID
        return redirect()->route('login');
    }

    public function registerGet()
    {
        return view('front.auth.register');
    }

    public function registerPost(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
            'password' => 'required|min:8|confirmed',
        ], [
            'name.required' => 'The name field is required.',
            'email.required' => 'The email field is required.',
            'email.email' => 'Please enter a valid email address.',
            'email.unique' => 'This email address is already registered.',
            'password.required' => 'The password field is required.',
            'password.min' => 'The password must be at least 8 characters.',
            'password.confirmed' => 'The password confirmation does not match.',
        ]);

        // Create a new user record
        $user = new User();
        $user->name = $request->input('name');
        $user->email = $request->input('email');
        $user->password = Hash::make($request->input('password'));
        $user->save();

        // Log in the newly registered user
        Auth::login($user);

        // Redirect the user to the home page or any other desired page
        return redirect()->intended('/');
    }
}
```

Your Login blade

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Sign In</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url('frontend/css/style.css') }}">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="main">
        <section class="signup">

            <div class="container">
                <div class="signup-content">

                    <form id="signup-form" class="signup-form" method="POST" action="{{ url('login') }}">
                        @csrf
                        <!--    <img src="images/logo.svg" alt="">-->
                        <h2 class="form-title">Login Here</h2>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="email" class="form-input" value="{{ old('email') }}" name="email"
                                id="email" placeholder="Your Email" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-input" name="password" id="password"
                                placeholder="Password" />
                            <span toggle="#password" class="zmdi zmdi-eye field-icon toggle-password"></span>
                        </div>
                        @error('email')
                            <div style="color: red">{{ $message }}</div>
                        @enderror

                        @error('password')
                            <div style="color: red">{{ $message }}</div>
                        @enderror
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="form-submit" value="Sign in" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <p class="loginhere">
                        New User? <a href="reg-form.html" class="loginhere-link">Register here</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Your Register page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Register</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url('frontend/css/style.css') }}">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="main">
        <section class="signup">

            <div class="container">
                <div class="signup-content">

                    <form id="signup-form" class="signup-form" method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                        @csrf
                        <h2 class="form-title">Register Here</h2>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-input" value="{{ old('name') }}" name="name" id="name"
                                placeholder="Your Name" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="email" class="form-input" value="{{ old('email') }}" name="email"
                                id="email" placeholder="Your Email" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="password" class="form-input" name="password" id="password"
                                placeholder="Password" />
                            <span toggle="#password" class="zmdi zmdi-eye field-icon toggle-password"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="password" class="form-input" name="password_confirmation"
                                id="password_confirmation" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
                        </div>
                        @error('name')
                            <div style="color: red">{{ $message }}</div>
                        @enderror

                        @error('email')
                            <div style="color: red">{{ $message }}</div>
                        @enderror

                        @error('password')
                            <div style="color: red">{{ $message }}</div>
                        @enderror

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="form-submit" value="Register" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <p class="loginhere">
                        Already have an account? <a href="{{ route('login') }}" class="loginhere-link">Login here</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I think This will solve your all queries

Answer (score 0):

hii your logout function is protected by middleware , you also need to add dashboard route a middleware you can group the routes that are required authentication middleware .

```
 Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', [AuthController::class, 'dashboard'])->name('dashboard');
    Route::post('/logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout'])->name('logout');
});
```

Comment: Hello Akshay ak, I have added the Auth middelware groupe function but now I am still on the login page but without the error messages.

Comment: Do i need to define the middleware someweare?